# ETH wallet offering API

Tags: wallets, myetherwallet, light-clients, python, external-api

I would like to develop a program that sends ETH. But I don't want to rely on an exchange such at bittrix or poloniex, as this causes delay (approving time), hassle (confirmation E-Mail), and often even additional costs (withdrawal fee).

Using a wallet, I can avoid these disadvantages. If I understand it correctly, even "online" wallets such as MyEtherWallet do not have these disadvantages.

Is there a (online) wallet offering a (REST) API? Or am I missing something and using a wallet is a stupid idea? How would you do it otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged your post with python, you might be especially interested in `web3.py` [docs](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/) and [github](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py).

Then you could run your own local `geth` node, and use python to send ether, using:

```
from web3 import Web3, IPCProvider

web3 = Web3(IPCProvider())

web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    'to': '0x5B2063246F2191f18F2675ceDB8b28102e957458',
    'from': web3.eth.coinbase,
    'value': 12345,
    })
```

Comment: Is there a solution that does not involve running a local geth node? More similar to a REST API e.g. offered by bitfinex?

Comment: Why did you use web3.eth.coinbase ?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with those type of solutions to give a thorough answer. Examples that I've seen tend to leave too much power in the hand of the wallet service. Whether it's an exchange or a wallet, if the ether is in a 3rd-party service, it's not your ether (they can walk away with it and you have no recourse).

Comment: I just thought coinbase looked cleaner than `web3.eth.accounts[0]`, but for most people it's the same thing.

Comment: true, however would be very convenient. No extra installation and running of software. Just a simple REST API call.

Comment: So did you guys able to find any open source API without any limit to create wallet?